# How do I replace a certain image on a website with another image?

Tags: image

There's this site that has an image I want to replace. Just like the scripts that replace the background of a page, like Google.

In the html, it's in `img scr`. How do I replace that specific source on the page with another source so every time I visit that page, it displays the image I want instead of the one that's normally there?

Comment: How do you load this site? How do you intend to replace the image? Javascript? CSS?

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you want to replace it dynamically when people with your add-on/script visit the page?  If so, try Greasemonkey.

Comment: Did you want to just modify the html source code to change the image that way?

Comment: Yeah, I want to replace it dynamically.

Comment: It's not possible in HTML, it's a static language, you have to use a dynamic language, such as PHP or ASP.net for serverside (everytime you load the page) or Javascript for client side (everytime you do a specific thing in the page).

Comment: Why in the world do you want to do this?

Answer (score 4):

A browser extension can accomplish this for you. I am familiar with how to do this with [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en) which my friend has made.

As an example I demonstrate how you would replace the Google logo image with Bing logo image with a simple rule:

[image: screenshot of rule config in Requestly]

and then on reloading the page after enabling the rule:

[image: bing logo on google homepage]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change it for yourself, [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) is ideal.  It lets you run a script (Kerin provides a starting point) every time you visit the page.  See these [Greasemonkey tutorials](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Tutorials#Greasemonkey_tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: It appears that you want to replace an image on a site that is not yours.**  If you do not have legitimate access to the site's webserver or CMS system, there is nothing you can do.  I'm leaving the rest of my post below just in case I have misinterpreted:

---

I'm assuming that you want to do this in Javascript, as you tagged your post with "Script."  Other script languages exist, of course, but only Javascript really has a meaningful installed base.

First you need to assign the image an ID, something like:

```
<img src="/images/cat.png" id="mypicture">
```

Then, inside your Javascript, you can alter the image's source like so:

```
document.getElementById('mypicture').src = "/images/dog.png";
```

You can take this technique pretty far, even adding stuff to the image tag like:

```
<img src="/images/cat.png" id="mypicture" onClick="document.getElementById('mypicture').src = '/images/dog.png';">
```

Comment: I can't assign an ID to the image, since I can't edit another website's html.

Comment: This isn't changing the image dynamically, is it? it changes it in a specific way only once.

Comment: Reddy, if it is another website's HTML then you will **not** be able to make changes that other users can see under any circumstances.

Comment: @Reddy: you can't change other websites, it not possible! we are talking about how to make it in your own pages.

Comment: That's the thing, I just want it for me to see that image differently, not for everyone. I don't want to edit the HTML itself, I'm very well aware that you can't do that. I just want a script to change it from my view.

Comment: Does the image have a NAME attribute, or is it inside a DIV with an ID?